# How to avoid alert "You won't be able to undo the changes this action query is about to make to the data in a linked table or tables"

Tags: ms-access, onclick, vba, alert, excel-external-data

I wrote a code to call a module on the button click in Access form and when I click on d button, i recieve d following alerts:

"You won't be able to undo the changes this action query is about to make to the data in a linked table or tables"

and

"You are about to update X row(s)".

The code behind the button is:

```
Private Sub UpdateRS_Click()
    Call UpdateModul.Update
End Sub
```

And module is:

```
Public Function Update()
DoCmd.RunSQL "Update tbl03 INNER JOIN tblMaster " & _
 "ON tbl03.KW = tblOnd_RS.KW " & _
 "SET tbl03.CAp = [tblMaster].[CAp] "
End Function
```

How to avoid these alert messages? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please show the code behind the button.

Comment: I just added the code behind the button (actually it is "Rectangle", but doesn't play much role I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/action-queries/SuppressWarningMessages.htm and http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/RunSQL_vs_Execute .

You could use

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE ..."
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

but this has multiple problems, e.g. an error could prevent `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` from running, which then could lead to disaster.

Much better is:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb  
db.Execute "UPDATE ...", dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Hi Andre, I used your first code, it is working, thank you very much. So far, I am satisfied with it, and I didn't understand the second code, but doesn't matter.